# How would I go about creating dynamic weapons using EC architecture?

Tags: c#, architecture, component-based, entity-component

I currently have a weapon component that contains common functionality across weapons  (mainly guns).

```
class Weapon : Component
{
    float fireRate;
    float reloadTime;

    void Reload() // Implements reload logic since it is common across all guns
}
```

The main thing that differentiates guns is firing (some deal splash damage, some fire in a cone, etc.)

The problem I am facing is how to implement the unique firing functionality? Should I make a `ConeDamage` component, a `LinearShot` component? If so how will it work?

Keep in mind I am using an EC architecture not ECS.

Comment: Your idea of distinct damage components makes sense to me. How have you tried implementing that so far, and where specifically did you get stuck, or find some unwanted behavior?

Comment: That's the part I am stuck in. How would I link the `Weapon` component with those unique components to create multiple weapons. Ex. a shotgun has the `Weapon` and `ConeDamage` components. How would the `Weapon` component know of its existence and use it.

Comment: How do components access or message other components in your system so far? Do you have an equivalent of things like GetComponent or SendMessage, or any kind of event system? This context will be important to include in your question to get high-quality answers.

Comment: Yes I do, more specifically the Nez framework for Monogame which is very similiar to Unitys.

Comment: Great. Be sure to edit your question to explain that, and clarify where you've run into trouble using those tools to interact between the weapon and damage components.